# Why checkstyle's checks requires compilation?

Tags: gradle

When I perform project's checking by CheckStyle in Maven, I type:

```
$ mvn checkstyle:checkstyle
```

and it only checks sources. But with Gradle when I run

```
$ gradle checkstyleMain
```

it also compiles java sources and process resources before checking.

Why gradle does that? Can this behavior to be turned off?

Answer (score 2):

Checkstyle (or at least some of its rules) needs the compiled classes in addition to the sources. You can prevent passing of the compiled classes (and thus compilation) with `tasks.withType(Checkstyle) { classpath = files() }`, but it may have negative consequences on the analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It would be interesting to know which rules require compiled sources..

Comment: Best ask on the Checkstyle list.